# Number of physicians in a hospital team

Tags: hospital

i recently came across a paper which used three physicians in the linear model formulation. Unfortunately there was no explanation in this paper and I can't find it in my history anymore. So I was wondering if there are any studies or websites that give information that a team size of three physicians is realistic? So that in hospitals, for example, there are only small teams per specialization?
I am very happy about any kind of help!

Comment: In the US, most physicians don't work in teams except in certain specialties (e.g. nocturnists). Solo practitioners cross cover, and medical groups are common. For a relatively small community hospital, a three-cardiologist "group" is fine, as is a three pediatrician "group", etc. As the size of the hospital and the services offered grows, so does the number of physicians needed to staff the hospital. I hope that helps. Googling your term offered only one paper.

Comment: I've worked in many hospitals as a moonlighter, with the smallest hospital having fewer than 3 of each primary specialty.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thanks for your answer. Which Paper did you find?